# Getting error trying to use Jsoup in Asynctask Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I'm trying to use Jsoup.connect to get to a website and get data, When I run my code as a java app it works fine, but when I run it in Asynctask in an android project, it crashes and gives me and error. I'm not sure why. Here's my code:

```
 public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        Log.v("jsoup", "running");
         try {
             Log.v("jsoup", "running1");
                Document doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston").get();
                Log.v("jsoup", "running2");
                Element contentDiv = ((Element) doc).select("div[id=content]").first();
                Log.v("jsoup", "running3");
                String output= contentDiv.toString();
                Log.v("jsoup", output);

            }catch (IOException e) {
            }
            return null;
    }
```

I'm getting an error when It hits the line that utilizes Jsoup.connect. Here's the first 3 lines of the error I'm getting:

```
07-12 12:30:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(686): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-12 12:30:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(686): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-12 12:30:42.296: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
```

Comment: Please, publish al the stack error, because there is the cause of the error. By the way, why are you casting the Document and Element? Try to delete that and keep the code clean.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error, though only with code that was run through Proguard.

Solved it by downgrading JSoup from 1.6.3 to 1.6.2